# T-Test with statistical significance

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

I have to undertake an unpaired t-test with the following dataset:

```
           Single        Team
Age         13,94        15,23
Size        1308,98      1126,28
Turnover    0,97         0,8
Expenses    0,01         0,01
```

How do I now do a t-test with the significance of the difference from the means being shown in the table when I´m finished? The values are all means.
So basically I want to compare the 13,94 (or 13.94) to the 15,23 (or 15.23) with each other and show, whether there is a statistically significant difference or not.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Im mainly having trouble with the formula, as R constantly tries to tell me, that there´s an unexpected "," even though it says that in the help section. I´m so confused right now and wish somebody could help me

Comment: What do you want to test? What do you want to know?

Comment: I want to compare the means of the variables on the left and look, whether the difference is significant (teams vs single managers)

Comment: So you want to compare the mean of $13$ and $94$ to the mean of $15$ and $23?$ Or are you using a comma to separate the integer part of a number and the decimal (something like $\pi\approx3,14159$)?

Comment: Ohhh I´m sorry. I´m from Germany and here the decimal point is , and not . sorry. 
Team and Single only have one number for each variable

Comment: And I just cant figure out how to do the t-test regarding every variable on the left and putting it into a table with the difference and the significance being shown

Comment: To conduct a T-test, you must be able to get the variance of both groups. Do you have the actual data set (or a value for variation) so that you can calculate this?

Comment: I have 19,000 observations for each of the variables, which I concluded in the mean. So, basically I have the values for each variable but I dont know how to use them correctly

Comment: You should be running the t-test on your original data, not on the summary statistics. Depending on exactly what you want to do, you might be better off doing a multivariate test (Hotelling's $T^2$ is the analogue of the t-test) or doing four univariate tests with adjustments for multiple testing, but you would have to elaborate on what you want to do before I would want to opine further.

Comment: I´m trying to do it as the literature I got, where the mean differences got looked at. 
They all are independent variables and I don´t further know how to elaborate this. 

I just want to compare the mean of the turnover of teams vs. single person and look, whether the difference is significant. 
I saw a unpaired t-test, where 2 variables got compared to each other, but I dont know how to do it myself unfortunately.

Thank you very much already, Im new to R as I have to learn it by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm speculating that you had $n_1 = 19\,000$ observations in vector `x1` with the following summary statistics; similarly for vector `x2`.  [I am showing results for fictitious data to illustrate the procedures. Results from your actual data may be different.]

```
summary(x1);  length(x1);  sd(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  5.506  12.346  13.935  13.940  15.490  21.924 
[1] 1900   # sample size
[1] 2.35   # sample standard deviation
summary(x2);  length(x2);  sd(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  4.577  13.028  15.144  15.230  17.336  26.650 
[1] 1900
[1] 3.19
```

Ideally, the data should be random samples from nearly-normal populations (at least nearly symmetrical and with no extreme outliers--for such large datasets a few moderate outliers are commonly seen).
Boxplots of the two samples suggest that the data are suitable for
a two-sample t test:

```
boxplot(x1, x2, col="skyblue2", horizontal=T)
```

[image]

Then look in a basic statistics text or online for the description
of a Welch 2-sample t test. The necessary ingredients are the
sample sample sizes $n_1=n_2=19\,000,$ sample means $\bar X_1 = 13.94, \bar X_2 = 15.23,$ and sample standard deviations $S_1 = 2.35, S_2 = 3.19.$ These are used to find the t statistic $T$ and the degrees of freedom (which will be large in your situation). [I suggest the Welch version of the 2-sample t test because it does not require that the two population variances be the same--not obvious in your situation.]

In R statistical software, the resulting test of the null hypothesis
$H_0: \mu_1=\mu_2$ against the alternative $H_1:\mu_1 \ne \mu_2$ is shown below. Other software programs use different formats to display the results, but mostly they show the test statistic, degrees of freedom, and P-value.

Clearly, $\bar X_1 \ne \bar X_2;$ the question is whether these sample means are sufficiently different to be declared 'significantly' different in a statistical sense at the 5% level.]

```
t.test(x1, x2)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = -44.878, df = 34929, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.34634 -1.23366
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
    13.94     15.23
```

The P-value (almost $0)$ is the probability of seeing such a large
difference between sample means if the two samples came from the same normal population. For a P-value smaller than $0.05 = 5\%,$ we
reject the null hypothesis at the 5% level, declaring the difference
statistically significant.

Roughly speaking, I suppose this is what @Dave means by "You should be running the t-test on your original data, not on the summary statistics."

You might do Welch t tests on Size and Turnover as well. I doubt you will find a difference for Expenses (unless you have additional places of accuracy, showing a difference). Or you might do a multivariate t test for all four measures simultaneously.

*Note:* Fictitious data for the discussion above were sampled in R as follows:

```
set.seed(2021)
z1 = rnorm(19000);  z1 = (z1-mean(z1))/sd(z1)
z2 = rnorm(19000);  z2 = (z2-mean(z2))/sd(z2)
x1 = z1*2.35 + 13.94
mean(x1);  sd(x1)
[1] 13.94
[1] 2.35
x2 = z2*3.19 + 15.23
mean(x2);  sd(x2)
[1] 15.23
[1] 3.19
```

Updated 5:40 PM US PDT 7/22 for sample sized 19,000.

Comment: First of all, thank you very very much ! 
I have 19,000 observations. However, according to the literature, it is enough to look at the mean of them I think. 
Could you maybe further explain the coding ? As Im a total Noob in R, I have difficulties in understanding what to type in, when doing such a test. 
For example, when I type this t-test: 
t.test((Single.Managers~Teams, alt=c("two.sided"),mu=0,paired=F,var.eq=F,conf.level=0.95, data = PData_Summary)
It gets it wrong. 
Im quite frustrated as Im not skilled enough to do it by myself. Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to have the two samples of 19,000 in a worksheet, dataframe, or vector. Syntax will vary from one program to another. In R, if you can name the samples `x1` and `x2`, then what I have shown suffices: `t.test(x1, x2)`. // This is not the place for basic instruction using statistical software, but for some programs (such as R) there are a lot of helpful pages online.

Comment: And how do I tell R which dataset it should take for the test ? :/

Comment: I have it saved as panel dataframe in R

Comment: Maybe start with an elementary statistics text. And the somewhat simpler pooled 2-sample t test. You would need to get the two sample standard deviations. Then plug the sample sizes, means and SDs into the appropriate formulas, and then draw conclusions based on the T statistic.

Comment: How do i get the Standard deviations from the means ? Or from the dataset ?

Comment: So I think I have to use the Welch t-test but how do i find out, whether the variances are the same ?

Comment: You don't. You need the original data for that. // How did you get the sample means? Is **anything at all** said about sample standard deviations $S$ or variances $S^2,$ or population $\sigma$ or $\sigma^2?$

Comment: No, I just have the 19,000 observations. Nothing is stated about anything you wrote

Comment: I calculated the mean with excel :|

Comment: That's one small step from computing the SD with Excel.

Comment: I now calculated the SD as well as the variance using excel and theyre not the same variance as well as SD

Comment: Do you know what I have to do now ?

Comment: Good news! You now have two sample sizes, two sample means, two sample SDs. That's all you need for a t test (pooled or Welch). Look up formulas in a text or online. Plug in to get $T$ statistic and degrees of freedom, and you're done. // It is permitted to answer your own question. When you finish the test, suggest you do so. (a) for confirmation, (b) for potential up-vote.

Comment: YES FINALLY, so I can now just run a Welch t-test with these values and that´s it ? 
You truly deserve a place in heaven. I´m so happy right now as it´s 2:30am and now I got it

Comment: Happy that you're happy. Schlafen gut!

Comment: You too :D Thank you very much!

Comment: I would give you upvotes etc. but Im only a Guest so I dont think I can do anything

Comment: Actually you seem to be 'fully enrolled' and already with 13 'reputation points'. If you're thinking about visiting repeatedly, maybe spend a few minutes 'taking the tour' of the site to use it to best advantage.

Comment: I signed up now, but I need to have 15. When I have them, I´ll come back to this question

Comment: Good to know my answer was useful. We all know that first-time visitors may not be able to up-vote an answer. Hope you enjoy the site. Many of the participants are amazingly helpful, knowledgeable and and experienced.

Comment: I dont doubt that with people like you. 
I have one small last question. How do I create a table with stargazer, showing the difference as well as the significance ?

Comment: Sorry, stargazer is one of many things I don't know about.

Comment: No worries, still thank you very much ! 
I know its a bit off-topic, but when I use the lag function (Variable,1) am I lagging it 1x into the future or the past ?

Comment: Almost surely the past. Usually to see if there is temporal correlation. If you have predictions into the future, they are likely associated with the past. "Prediction is difficult--especially about the future." (Source: Danish proverb, Niels Bohr, Albert Einstein, or American baseball player Yogi Berra, take your choice.)

Comment: Okey, thank you very much. I´ll take Albert :D 
Does it make a difference whether I take the normal data or the panel data as dataset for the t-test? :)